# Why is Python class not recognizing static variable

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, static

I am trying to make a class in Python with static variables and methods (attributes and behaviors)

```
import numpy

class SimpleString():    
    popSize = 1000 
    displaySize = 5
    alphatbet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "

    def __init__(self):
        pop = numpy.empty(popSize, object)
        target = getTarget()
        targetSize = len(target)
```

When the code runs though it says that it cannot make the array pop because popSize is not defined

Comment: Attributes must always be accessed with `self`, e.g., `self.popSize`.

Comment: or `SimpleString.popSize` .... when it is static class variable ... (if you access it with self changes will not reflect back to the classvariable)

Comment: you misspelled alphabet ;-) GRAMMAR NAZI ftw

Comment: Nick, join me in [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41210/conversation) chat room

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You either need to access it with a `self.popSize` or `SimpleString.popSize`. When you declare a variable in a class in order for any of the instance functions to access that variable you will need to use `self` or the class name(in this case `SimpleString`) otherwise it will treat any variable in the function to be a local variable to that function.

The difference between `self` and `SimpleString` is that with `self` any changes you make to `popSize` will only be reflected within the scope of your instance, if you create another instance of `SimpleString` `popSize` will still be `1000`. If you use `SimpleString.popSize` then any change you make to that variable will be propagated to any instance of that class.

```
import numpy

class SimpleString():    
    popSize = 1000 
    displaySize = 5
    alphatbet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "

    def __init__(self):
        pop = numpy.empty(self.popSize, object)
        target = getTarget()
        targetSize = len(target)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `self` or the class object to access class attributes:

```
def __init__(self):
    pop = numpy.empty(self.popSize, object)
    target = getTarget()
    targetSize = len(target)
```

or

```
def __init__(self):
    pop = numpy.empty(SimpleString.popSize, object)
    target = getTarget()
    targetSize = len(target)
```

The latter form is really only needed if you want to bypass an instance attribute with the same name:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     bar = 42
...     baz = 42
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = 38
...     def printBar(self):
...         print self.bar, Foo.bar
...     def printBaz(self):
...         print self.baz, Foo.baz
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.printBar()
38 42
>>> f.printBaz()
42 42
```

Here `self.bar` is an instance attribute (setting always happens on the object directly). But  because there is no `baz` instance attribute, `self.baz` finds the class attribute instead.

Comment: you would also use the latter if you wanted to modify it in one class instance and see the change reflected in other class instances (like a static variable :P)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: the term 'static variable' is really misplaced here; Python has 'class attributes' and 'instance attributes'.

Comment: yes however class attributes behave like static variables in other languages (for the most part) ...