# Flattening nested generator expressions

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I'm trying to flatten a nested generator of generators but I'm getting an unexpected result:

```
>>> g = ((3*i + j for j in range(3)) for i in range(3))
>>> list(itertools.chain(*g))
[6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8]
```

I expected the result to look like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I think I'm getting the unexpected result because the inner generators are not being evaluated until the outer generator has already been iterated over, setting `i` to 2. I can hack together a solution by forcing evaluation of the inner generators by using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression:

```
>>> g = ([3*i + j for j in range(3)] for i in range(3))
>>> list(itertools.chain(*g))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Ideally, I would like a solution that's completely lazy and doesn't force evaluation of the inner nested elements until they're used.

Is there a way to flatten nested generator expressions of arbitrary depth (maybe using something other than `itertools.chain`)?

**Edit:**

No, my question is not a duplicate of [Variable Scope In Generators In Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848736/variable-scope-in-generators-in-classes). I honestly can't tell how these two questions are related at all. Maybe the moderator could explain why he thinks this is a duplicate.

Also, both answers to my question are correct in that they can be used to write a function that flattens nested generators correctly.

```
def flattened1(iterable):
    iter1, iter2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
    if isinstance(next(iter1), collections.Iterable):
        return flattened1(x for y in iter2 for x in y)
    else:
        return iter2

def flattened2(iterable):
    iter1, iter2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
    if isinstance(next(iter1), collections.Iterable):
        return flattened2(itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter2))
    else:
        return iter2
```

As far as I can tell with `timeit`, they both perform identically.

```
>>> timeit(test1, setup1, number=1000000)
18.173431718023494
>>> timeit(test2, setup2, number=1000000)
17.854709611972794
```

I'm not sure which one is better from a style standpoint either, since `x for y in iter2 for x in y` is a bit of a brain twister, but arguably more elegant than `itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter2)`. Input is appreciated.

Regrettably, I was only able to mark one of the two equally good answers correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `chain(*g)`, you can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> g = ((3*i + j for j in range(3)) for i in range(3))
>>> list(itertools.chain(*g))
[6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8]
>>> g = ((3*i + j for j in range(3)) for i in range(3))
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(g))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```
[x for y in g for x in y]
```

Which yields:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Guess you already have your answer, but here's another perspective.

The problem is that when each inner generator is created, the value-generating expression is closed over the outer variable `i` so even when the first inner generator starts generating values, it's using the "current" value of `i`.  This will have value `i=2` if the outer generator has been fully consumed (and that's exactly the case right after the argument in the `chain(*g)` call is evaluated, before `chain` is actually called).

The following devious trick will work around the problem:

```
g = ((3*i1 + j for i1 in [i] for j in range(3)) for i in range(3))
```

Note that these inner generators *aren't* closed over `i` because the `for` clauses are evaluated at generator creation time so the singleton list `[i]` is evaluated and its value "frozen" in the face of further changes to the value of `i`.

This approach has the advantage over the `from_iterable` answer that it's a little more general if you want to use it outside a `chain.from_iterable` call -- it will always produce the "correct" inner generators, whether the outer generator is partially or fully consumed before the inner generators are used.  For example, in the following code:

```
g = ((3*i1 + j for i1 in [i] for j in range(3)) for i in range(3))
g1 = next(g)
g2 = next(g)
g3 = next(g)
```

you can insert the lines:

```
list(g1)
list(g2)
list(g3)
```

in any order at any point after the respective inner generator has been defined, and you'll get the correct results.

Comment: +1 This is really sneaky and really cool, but it doesn't help me flatten the nested generator that I started with.

Comment: No, I guess you're right!  Though, if you are constructing nested generators in such a way that the values of the inner generators depends on the timing of evaluation of the outer generators, it's a programming time bomb -- some minor refactoring of code will cause everything to blow up.  It might be a good idea to redesign the inner generators to avoid the undesirable variable capture, no matter how you decide to flatten `g` in the end.

Comment: Everything you've said is true, but my (unstated) goal is not to use generators like those everywhere (`range()` generates flattened ranges of numbers just fine), but to enable other programmers to define multidimensional arrays using generators. If they think that their multidimensional array looks like [[0,1],[2,3]] when in fact it looks like [[2,3],[2,3]] -- all without raising any errors -- then I've screwed up.